# Convert new lines from linux to windows using replaceregexp with ant

Tags: regex, linux, ant, newline

I want to convert all source code to a windows line line using replaceregexp on an ant script but for more combinations I try I failed.

I have tried with the next code but it prints literal "rl":

```
<replaceregexp match="\n" replace="\r\n" flags="g" byline="false" >
    <fileset dir="${src}">
        <include name="**/*.java" />
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

I can't use `${line.separator}` because I'm executing the ant script from linux so it's evaluated to `\n`.

It can be done? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Ant [`<fixcrlf>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) task which is specifically for this purpose. Something like:

```
<fixcrlf eol="crlf" srcdir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" />
```

Also has the advantage that it's safely repeatable without adding multiple `\r` characters.

To insert the CRLF yourself using the `replaceregexp` task use XML entities:

```
... replace="&#13;&#10;" ...
```